# ImportError: cannot import name 'Patches' from 'matplotlib.patches'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to play a plot from a video, but I'm getting the following error - **ImportError: cannot import name 'Patches' from 'matplotlib.patches'**

[ImportError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zETNr.png)

My code:

```
from colour import Color
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.patches import Patches as mpatches

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='blue')

#DC
plt.scatter(X[0], Y[0],color='red', marker='D')
plt.annotate("DC",(X[0]-1,Y[0]-5.5))

#imprimir as rotas
for r in range(len(rotas)):
    for n in range(len(rotas[r])-1):
        i = rotas[r][n]
        j = rotas[r][n+1]
        plt.plot([X[i],X[j]], [Y[i],Y[j]], color=Color(r), alpha=0.4)
    
for r in range(len(temp_acum)):
for n in range(len(temp_acum[r])):
    i = rotas[r][n]
    plt.annotate('$q_{%d}=%d$ |$t_{%d}=%d$'  %(i, q[i], i, temp_acum[r][n]), (X[i]+1,Y[i]))
    
patch = [mpatches.Patch(color=Color(n), label="Veiculo "+str(truck[n])+"|cap="+str(Q[truck[n]])) for n in range(len(truck))]
plt.legend(handles=patch,loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Distância X')
plt.ylabel('Distância Y')
plt.title('CVRPTW | Problema de Roteamento de Veículos com Janela de Tempos')
     
plt.show()
```

Comment: It should just be `from matplotlib.patches import Patch as mpatch` as `Patches` isn't an object that is available in Matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matt said in comments:

Yes, it should be

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch as mpatch
```

it is `Patch` instead of `Patches`

link to document https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html

Comment: New error: from matplotlib.patches import Patch as mpatch

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Due to the size, I attached it to Codepad: http://codepad.org/d7m3mYqB